# HDFS - put race condition

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

If I use `copyFromLocalFile()` to put a file in HDFS, with overwrite set to `false`, what will happen if a second process calls `copyFromLocalFile()` writing to the same location on HDFS also with overwrite set to `false` before the first put completes?

If the second call will throw an `IOException` is there a way I can determine that the exception was due to an existing put operation currently in progress and not because of network failure or some other issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDFS allows for atomic creation, so the second write will fail.

(source: personal experience as an active HDFS developer)

The second call will throw a `FileAlreadyExistsException` as documented by `ClientProtocol` [in its Javadoc](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/protocol/ClientProtocol.java#L188).